# X++ select statement on related tabled

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax7

I need help to get data from prodtable that are related to salesline.
My task is to get all Prodid that are related to current salesid. Related field prodtable.inventrefid == salesline.salesid. But the values are a bit differend to join so I get no data. Inventrefid have eg. ZPR0000011 and sales id is ZS00000011.

```
salesline tablebuffer = this.cursor();  
while select ProdId, CollectRefProdId from prodtable where prodtable.inventrefid == 'ZPR00000165'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you should include `InventRefType::Sales` and `SalesStatus::Backorder` in your select statement. Take a look at relation `SalesOrder` of table `ProdTable`.

Comment: You say related to `salesline` and also related to `salesid`. Those are two different statements, which is it? Why are you doing `this.cursor()`? That implies you're in a form datasource...which leads to further questions, are you trying to create a link or what are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: As for now I just tried to get data. Im now very familiar with formstr and formdatasourcestrn and I dont know much about the differences, coins and pros of using them. It was just more easy for me to use cursor() method so I picked formsdatasourcestr.
I wanted to get the data,  check it and in return enable a checkbox (or do nothing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I immediately see is:

> `prodtable.inventrefid == 'ZPR00000165'`

`inventRefId` would be your `SalesId`, which is `ZS00000011` **not** your `ProdId`.

An example of a more correct query is below. You can refine it by joining the two selects together so you get all related `ProdTable` records to **all** `SalesLine` records for a given `SalesId` and you can also specify fields in the queries so that you are not returning the entire buffer.

```cs
SalesLine           salesLine;
ProdTable           prodTable;

/*
This just chooses the first sales line with that salesid. You would need to join these together
if you wanted to do all sales lines in one query.
*/
select firstOnly salesLine
    where salesLine.SalesStatus                 == SalesStatus::Backorder       &&
          salesLine.SalesId                     == 'ZS00000011';

while select prodTable
    where prodTable.InventRefTransId            == salesLine.InventTransId      &&
          prodTable.InventRefId                 == salesLine.SalesId            &&
          prodTable.InventRefType               == InventRefType::Sales
{
    info(strFmt("Found related ProdTable record %1 - %2 (%3)", prodTable.ProdId, prodTable.CollectRefProdId, prodTable.RecId));
}
```

Comment: The problem is I didn't know that I need to use Backorder and ::Sales in select. And since it didn't worked when I just did prodtable.inventrefid == salesline.salesid I was thinking the problem was that salesid was all ZS and in refid ZPR..

Comment: @RadosławMierzejewski It's helpful to look at the table relations when trying to create a select statement. See `\Data Dictionary\Tables\ProdTable\Relations\SalesOrder` to see how I knew those were needed in the select. Glad I could help!